# Is there a topos in which the natural numbers object are the finite dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I recall reading somewhere that there is a topos in which the Dedekind reals are exactly the measurable functions.

Now vector spaces are prominently characterised by dimensionality. This prompted the thought as to whether there is a topos in which the natural numbers object are the finite-dimensional vector spaces (upto isomorphism); and if there is such a topos, what would the Dedekind reals be there?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. If you only care about finite-dimensional vector spaces (over a given field) up to isomorphism, then the set of isomorphism classes can be canonically identified with the natural numbers. But the collection of all finite-dimensional vector spaces is not itself a set.

Comment: @Lin: Thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected the question. I'd say its a little harsh to say that this question doesn't make sense when such a small modification makes it correct. If this was a literary contest, I'd say its more akin to a spelling mistake as opposed to being an entirely ungrammatical sentence.

Comment: But then the modified question is boring: $\mathbf{Set}$ is such a topos!

Comment: @Lin: That surprises me, I'd have thought the NNO in Set is just the ordinary integers.

Comment: Any countable set can be an NNO in $\mathbf{Set}$ – NNOs are only unique up to unique isomorphism. Please learn some category theory.

Comment: Naively, I'd think the issue with such a topos is that we can't simply replace vector spaces with the natural number that characterizes their dimension. For example, classifying pairs of subspaces of a vector space also requires you to take into account the intersection of the subspaces (not just their dimensions). (While looking into your question, @Mozibur, I came across "a sheaf theoretic approach to measure theory": https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/students/jackson.pdf, who reference's Scott's Boolean Models and Nonstandard Analysis, is this what you were referencing?)

Comment: An interpretation of your question might be "Is there is a topos with a natural numbers object that corresponds to the finite-dimensional vector spaces in some more natural way than in the category of sets?" I do not know the answer.  What came to mind when I read your question is the notion of a smooth topos, which you might find interesting. This does not have finite n-dimensional vector spaces as the NNO, rather, I think smooth n-dimensional spaces are the NNO in a smooth topos. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+topos

Comment: With respect to your interest in the "Dedekind reals" wrt vector space dimension, a concept of the same flavour is von Neumann's generalized theory of dimension: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_geometry

Comment: @catherine Ray: yes, that's right; it was Jacksons thesis that provoked the question; your suggestion of smooth topoi is interesting as is the continuous geometry of Neumanns - I had heard of them, but didn't think to make the connection.

Comment: That they and Jackson use lattices is I think intriguing.